# Where to find Kuratowski's Theorem?

Tags: reference-request, descriptive-set-theory

I am looking for a Theorem by Kuratowski stating something like:

For any two Polish Spaces $A,B$ there are meager sets $M_1 \subseteq A$, $M_2 \subseteq B$ and a homeomorphism $f: A \setminus M_1 \rightarrow B \setminus M_2$.

Does anybody know the title of the original paper and where to find it - or another source?

Thanks.

Comment: Do the spaces need to be perfect?

Answer (score 3):

I’ve not been able to track down the original source, but [this paper](http://www.math.fu-berlin.de/~geschke/papers/mbt5.pdf) by Stefan Geschke (who sometimes posts here) states the theorem as follows:

> For any perfect Polish spaces $X$ and $Y$ there are meagre Borel sets $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$ such that $X\setminus A$ and $Y\setminus B$ are homeomorphic.

The reference is to K. Kuratowski, *Topology*, vol. 1, 1966, no page number given.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!

Comment: @Rolfor: You’re welcome! I wish that I’d found a more specific source.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not find the theorem in Kuratowski's book. Does anybody know the original paper?